# jquery 2.2.3 get undefined for "data" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery 2.2.3 and I have this div:

```
<div class="typeahead" data-minLength="1" data-queryURL="url"></div>
```

If I do:

```
console.log(jQuery('.typeahead').attr('data-queryURL')
```

I get "url".

If I do:

```
console.log(jQuery('.typeahead').data('queryURL')
```

I get "undefined".

Comment: have you added/modified the data-queryURL with jquery before calls it ? or is html defined only? if you have modified it with .attr, you only can call it with .attr, samely with .data modified

Comment: I do not know, I do not have all control of the code. Probably you are right, someway it has been modified with attr.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro  check this thread:- https://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-6-1-html5-data-attributes-data-somevalue-doesn-t-work

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery `.data()` support lowercase key name.

```
console.log(jQuery('.typeahead').data('queryurl'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uppercase characters are not supported in data-* attributes. The HTML5 spec says:

3.2.3.8 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes
A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

Explained also [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-dataset).

This works well:

```
console.log(jQuery('.typeahead').attr('data-queryurl'));
console.log(jQuery('.typeahead').data('queryurl'));
```